# kNN classifier in multi-label settings with WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, knn

WEKA has profound support for kNN classifiers (many different distances and etc.)

Unfortunately WEKA doesn't support [multi-label problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification).

One of the solutions can be to use binary relevance approach.

I am not sure whether it's a correct workaround? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Meka](http://meka.sourceforge.net/) which is based on Weka and is expected to handle multilabel classification problems.

Comment: Thank you very much! However it's not clear how to run kNN. I subscribed to meka mailing list and currently I am waiting for confirmation. Do you know how to run kNN?